# Is this generic extension method thread safe for logging?

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0

I have below Extension Method. I am passing all values as parameters.I would like to know whether it is a thread safe method if this method accessible by the multiple threads.

```
 public static string ConcatLogKeyWithExceptionMessage<T>(this T entity, string configuredLogKeys, bool logOnlySingleKey, string exceptionMessage, bool firstInvocation = true, StringBuilder logKeyBuilder = null, string[] configuredKeysArray = null) where T : class
    {
    }
```

If you need more info please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Thread safety is a concern about how the data behaves when multiple threads access it at the same time. When is said that a method is thread safe, it means that either the method content is caring of synchronizing access to non-thread safe data structures; the data structures manipulated with the method are inherently thread safe; or both.

If your method is thread safe or not, will depend on if for example the members of `T entity` that you are manipulating are thread safe or not. The same for the `StringBuilder`, the array, and anything that is passed by reference. If that method is a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) you could say it is thread safe. However, if that method is causing side effects in any of the parameters, it would depend on how those changes are performed.